# Interrupt and Resuming a Foreach Loop

Tags: php, foreach

I have the following array of brands:

```
$brand=array('brand1','brand2','brand3');
```

The goal is to create a link in the navigation menu for each of the brands, so I could run the following to achieve that:

```
sort($brand);
foreach ($brand as &$bval) {
$bval2 = strtolower($bval);
$bval3 = str_replace(" ", "-", $bval2);
echo '<li><a href="/?detail='.$bval3.'"';
//See note below
echo '><span>'.$bval.'</span></a></li>';
}
```

All of that works just fine. However, in order to indicate in the navigation menu which brand is selected, the link needs `class="tactive"` inside of it. In order to figure out which brand is selected, I could use something like what I have below and insert it where I have the `//See note below` comment in the code above. (`$currentbrand` would be defined in the file containing all of the page data):

```
if ($_GET[detail]=$currentbrand) {
echo 'class="tactive"';
}
```

However, in order for every link to not be marked as active, this would need to be done outside of the `foreach` loop. Could I interrupt the `foreach` loop, add the code that I need to, and then resume it in order to have the last part of the link there?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *in order for every link to not be marked as active, this would need to be done outside of the foreach loop*

this is the wrong assumption. What you really need to do, is to *compare* instead of *assign*:

```
if ($_GET['detail'] == $currentbrand) {
  echo 'class="tactive"';
}
```

for otherwise the expression would be determined by whether `$currentbrand` is true or false.

---

Also, you could rewrite your code a bit and reduce the number of unneeded variables and string-concatenations. One example might be:

```
sort($brand);
foreach ($brand as $bval) {
  $alias = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($bval));

  printf(
    '<li><a href="/?detail=%s" class="%s"><span>%s</span></a></li>',
    $alias,
    isset($_GET['detail']) && $alias === $_GET['detail'] ? 'tactive' : '',
    $bval
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! That's a good point and something that I somehow neglected to notice, but all of the links are still marked as active when I compare instead of assign.

Comment: Could you post a bit more of your code. For example the `$currentbrand` variable issn't defined in the excerpt you posted. Did you try the alternative code?

Comment: Yeah, the new code didn't work either. `$currentbrand` would just be one of the values from the `$brand` array that was shown in my first post, depending on which page was being shown.

Comment: I had an error it the example regarding the url-value, have a look.

Comment: Well, it would appear as though your example did work after all, I think that I didn't copy all of it before. Thank you for the help!